# Consumer group can't rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am learning kafka and now I am having some problems with the example code i've found here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

Each time I run the code it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: ttt_NB644-1475151991986-76dfa03f can't rebalance after 4 retries
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:670)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:977)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:264)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:85)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:97)
at com.glowbyte.kafka.consumertest.ConsumerGroupExample.run(ConsumerGroupExample.java:44)
at com.glowbyte.kafka.consumertest.ConsumerGroupExample.main(ConsumerGroupExample.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The kafka version which I'm using is 0.10, the latest one.
There is only one topic with one broker and two partitions, and I'm trying to run the code with 2 threads.

In the meantime, another code, just more simple, runs successfully on the same environment with also 2 threads. So I'd like to understand what's causing the described exception. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: i have the same issue, have resolved it? @griboedov